# should the dinosaurs roar (or scream) in my mesozoic world?

Tags: biology, dinosaurs

I have never seen a reptile/bird doing that, may be some of the species do chirping/clicking or a hissing sound.

Imagine earth in mesozoic era, can I assume the giant faunas could make a roaring sound, specially a carnivorous theropod ?

If yes, why ?

Comment: If you're asking why dinosaurs roar in media, then your question is off-topic for this site. However, if you are trying to envision a fictional world where dinosaurs do roar and you're trying to come up with an explanation as to why they would do this, then we can help you.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish thanks, edited.

Comment: Isn't this question a bit too wide? Dinosaurs were found in every size and shape, adapted to living in extremely different ways, it stands to reason that they would make sounds with equal variation, from honks and roars to hisses and chirps. If you are curious about a few specific dinosaurs you would probably have better luck narrowing the question down. Still, asking about roars makes me believe you are curious about t-rex like dinos, in which case this text and animation should give you some clues http://nerdist.com/is-this-what-tyrannosaurus-rex-really-sound-like/

Comment: ...What does the fox-osaurus say?

Comment: only parasaurs and other dinosaurs with specialized horns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dinosaurs in general, and more specifically theropods, I would look to modern archosaurs for reference, these would be birds and crocodilians.

Dinosaurs were part of the group of animals mentioned above, and so many would likely make similar sounds. You would think that that's a pretty wide range, but most dinosaurs probably lacked a sirynx (the organ most modern birds use to vocalize, roughly analogous our vocal cords). As such the modern cassowary (http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4dcQO6Zb8Eg) and crocodilians (http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Jkh3sknNnkI) should provide good inspiration.

As for lambeosaurines (crested duckbills), their sometimes impressive crests would create very loud, whistle-like, trumpeting, and/or booming calls. Different shaped crests would produce different notes, and those with the largest crests would likely be the loudest.

Sauropods likely communicated largely through tail cracks, and, like elephants, stomping, sending infrasound rolling through the earth, which other sauropods would be able to pick up from great distances.

Keep in mind though that the sounds an animal make tend to be rather influenced by its lifestyle. Herbivores will be noisier, to keep in communication with the animals around them. But animals that live herds may not need to be especially loud, unless that is selected for in the mating process (like the lambeosaurines). Whereas pack predators may make only signaling sounds while the prowl, and solitary predators may rarely make any sounds at all.

Another important note Is that, in modern habitats, forest and jungle animals are often the loudest, and have the most elaborate calls. While animals that live in more open habitats are more likely to favor visual communication.

As for why a giant carnivore would roar, well, why else? They'd do it to look scary, to say, I'm big, and I'm tough, don't mess with me. The most likely times for an animal like that to roar would be when they where trying to scare off a potential threat. Or, attract a potential mate, seeing as they would generally live good distances apart, and would need to be loud to get the attention of others. Though they may be noisier when they have chicks around as a way to frighten smaller predators, that may pose a threat to their young, away.

All in all, there was an incredible amount of diversity in the dinosaur kingdom, but I would look to the YouTube links I provided above. Using sounds like those should supply you with an interesting, realistic, and sometimes very intimidating, "vocabulary" for your dinosaurs.

**Edit:** Just noticed the link to an article that makes some similar suggestions in the comments below the OP.

Comment: You make good points :)

Answer (score 2):

I've come across a few cases where it was determined what sound was made by specific dinosaurs.

1. A huge bassoon on the head connected through the sinus system. The sound is determined by the shape of the chamber,  ot the material it's made of, so they build a model and blew into it.
2. Something about the ears. They figured the parents and babies used a particular frequency range, and maybe something more about the kind of cheeping.
3. The tail can crack like a whip, making a noise like a 50 cm naval artillery shell.  Apparently used as a mating call.

Why would giant fauna "roar"? Are you talking of ambush predators? I think they would like to be silent. Scavengers? Again, *why*?  Maybe huge herbivores made loud noise to scare off the predator or alert the herd.

Note that dinosaurs, across several very different general types, filled all niches and had many different lifestyles. That's like asking a blanket question about all mammals.  Do they roar? Well, a few do, but that is not a general characteristic of being a mammal.

So if you are describing a rich world, forget roaring. Describe each species individually with its own characteristics, and invent noises based on known examples from the niche they fill or specific behavior they engage in. So make them cheep, bray, honk, bellow, etc. as inspiration strikes you.

Comment: I think you forgot protecting territory and competing with the same species... Various animals that almost never use sound, not even for mating, will 'roar' in their own way to scare competitors out of their terriories, while fighting with others of their own species, etc. That characteristic is quite 'cross-nichal' to say it in some way, from rats and cats to elephants and rorquals. I think mostly to 'fight' in some way without risking physical integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Birds are descended from dinosaurs. Are there any fossils to confirm whether dinosaurs had a syrinx as birds do? Anyway on that assumption dinosaurs would have made  bird like noises. Big dinosaurs, probably much deeper in pitch than extant birds.

Roaring requires a mammalian larynx. Loud roaring is part of a threat display prior to (or part of) aggressive action. There's also a grunt-roar by some predators as they pounce. That is involuntary expulsion of air from mammalian lungs caused by muscular exertion. Bird and dinosaur lungs are structured completely differently.

It's probably worth noting that birds' alarm calls are fairly universal: a rapidly repeated piercing screech. This is not very surprising. There is probably a large instinctive component to making this noise and in responding to it. Also a species' survival chances is boosted by responding to other species' raising of a threat alarm. And there is common ancestry.

In passing why do human electromechanical alarm-raisers often make a piercing rapidly repeated screech? Mammals probably also have the same instinctive response to that sound pattern.

So I think it's a fair bet that a herd of startled dinosaurs sounded like a flock of startled birds transposed down an octave or two!

What we'll never know is what other sounds dinosaurs.might have made. Might they have provided alto, tenor and even bass to the songbird's treble? What might dawn have sounded like 66M years ago the day  before the meteor struck?

Comment: You can take a look at this (http://io9.gizmodo.com/what-sound-did-t-rex-actually-make-1591173199) article for more detail, but simply put, it seems fairly unlikely that most dinosaurs possessed a syrinx. It seems they lacked the necessary bone structure for the function of one up until the point where they became much more like modern birds.

Answer (score 0):

There were some major clads of dinosaurs. Let us analyze their probable sound patterns.

## Ornithischia - Ornithopoda

These include the *duck-billed* dinosaurs such as iguanodons, camptosaurs and hadrosaurs. Some of these had upto 12 feet long tubes in their nasal passages which are thought to serve as sound amplifiers. These dinosaurs are most likely to make low-frequency, long, horn-like calls.

## Ornithischia - Marginocephalia - Pachycephalosauria

They were *bone-heads* of mesozoic. Their skulls had *very* thick forehead bones. It is unclear whether these dinosaurs would have made any sophisticated calls like modern day goats or cattle, but short whines and grumbling sounds would *probably* have been made.

## Ornithischia - Marginocephalia - Ceratopsia

The bison and buffaloes of mesozoic. It is very likely that these bossy, giant creatures would have made short, grunting sounds like modern day cattle. However they would have probably only grunted when threatening an intruder (or predator) or during the mating season.

## Ornithischia - Thyreophora - Stegosauria

The famous, plated dinosaurs! With very small beaks (as compared to their aggregate body sizes) and very small brains, it is very unlikely that they have made any sounds at all, except when whining in pain.

## Ornithischia - Thyreophora - Ankylosauria

The tanks of mesozoic. Like the stegosaurs, these too, had small, beak-like mouths and tiny brains. It is highly unlikely that they would have made any sounds.

## Saurischia - Sauropodomorpha

The ***giants*** of mesozoic! With extremely long necks and extremely small brain sizes (versus body size), it is extremely unlikely that they were capable of making any sounds at all. Even when panicking or standing their ground against a predator, these giants would almost certainly have been completely mute.

## Saurischia - Theropoda - Coelurosauria

The *bird-like* hunters. These include creatures such as archaeopteryx, oviraptors, dromeosaurs, troodonts and the famous tyrannosaurs. With quite developed brains and close relationship to birds, it is highly likely that they would have made elaborate calls for threat display, mating and social grouping. They are also likely to have called (screamed) when chasing their prey. However, the larger the size of the creature, the less detailed would their calls be. Small ovirapors and deinonychus would probably have had much more advanced calling system (like wolves) while tyrannosaurs would have behaved more like jaguars.

## Saurischia - Theropoda - Ceratosauria

These were the heavily built, powerful predators of southern continents(Africa and South America). While some form of mate-calls and threat-display deep groans cannot be ruled out completely, these monsters were not closely related to birds and it is less likely that they would have an elaborate calling system (like small to medium sized coelurosaurs).

Comment: While I commend you for your effort and your knowledge about different families of dinosaurs, you seem to be basing your claims of how they would sound on little more than your own speculations. Shouldn't you make more of a case for why " these giants would almost certainly have been completely mute." and "tyrannosaurs would have behaved more like jaguars"? it reads a bit silly to me the way it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, before I say anything, it should be noted that, given the very dead nature of dinosaurs (excluding birds of course, but I'll get to that), it is *very* difficult to even speculate with credibility what they could have sounded like, let alone pin down exactly what they sounded like. However, there are one or two instances where we can get close or have a good idea what could be modern equivalents.

**HERBIVORES** -Regarding herbivorous dinosaurs, we have a few instances where we can get pretty close to what they sounded like, specifically in regards to Hadrosaurs (aka 'duck bills'to some). Some time in the mid 90s, scientists in New Mexico were able to produce sounds that *could* (emphasis on could) have been made by the owner of one of the strangest heads in dinosauria: Parasaurolophus. Using CT scans of its strange crested skull and computer software, they created a low frequency sound that is haunting to say the least.(More info on that here: http://www.sandia.gov/media/dinosaur.htm) Some audio of the sound is still floating around on the internet, and can be found on Youtube. How it likely made such sounds was by blowing air through various tubes in the crest that exited as low frequency sounds that could travel long distances. The fact that the calls were low frequency actually makes a lot of sense if we look at a combination of the dinosaurs' direct descendants as well as large animals like elephants. In regards to the Birds, several species (especially larger ones like cassowaries and emus) are known to emit low frequency calls and rumbles that are barely audible to humans (a bit like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wB3BKHmxZ4). Elephants are known to make similar rumbles to communicate over both long and short distances (more info here: http://www.elephantvoices.org/elephant-communication/acoustic-communication.html), so its logical to think that animals of similar size that have descendants that make similar low frequency rumbles also made such sounds. In addition, higher frequency calls are possible to have been made, depending on whether or not dinosaurs had a larnyx (like a crocodile) or syrinx (like a bird). It is entirely possible that they had niether or one of these, but we just can't know for sure until we get some incredible soft tissue fossil.

**CARNIVORES** - Here's where things get trickier. We don't have crest recreations or any of that fancy stuff for these guys, and its likely that they were quieter than herbivores because of their need for stealth when hunting anyways. However, that doesn't mean they were entirely silent. Most likely, carnivores (or any dinosaur for that matter) didn't roar in the way that a mammal roars. The way mammals make sound is entirely different from the way birds make sound. Its more likely that they could have growled (like a crocodilian) to an extent, hissed (also like a crocodilian, but birds, namely geese, are also known to hiss in a very menacing fashion), and possibly screeched like some modern day birds in some cases. For a theoretically accurate dinosaur 'roar', look no farther than Saurian, a game being developed around the most up to date dinosaur facts possible. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HD8AIlm97lA) Other than that, in the words of Mark Witton (a famous paleoartist and a very knowledgeable person in my opinion), "In the absence of proper data, speculate wildly." Since we can never truly know for sure with the current amount of data we have, some 'wiggle room' so to speak is allowed.